# c++ covariance, call child method

Tags: c++, c++17, covariant-return-types

I create two simple classes by inheritance, and I add a virtual function and the override in the child class.

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual Base* getThis() { std::cout << "called Base::getThis()\n"; return this; }
    virtual void func1() { std::cout << "called Base::func1\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived* getThis() override { std::cout << "called Derived::getThis()\n";  return this; }
    void func1() override { std::cout << "called Derived::func1\n"; }
    void func2() { std::cout << "called Derived::func2\n"; }
};
```

With c++ covariance, I can do this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Derived d{};
    Base* b{ &d };
    b->getThis()->func1();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I would like to call `Derived::func2`.

```cpp
b->getThis()->func2();
```

The previous code produces the following error: `error: 'class Base' has no member named 'func2';`

The only solution I have:

```cpp
dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b->getThis())->func2();
```

Do we have to use `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast`, to call `Derived::func2`?
Is there another method?

Comment: From OOP point of view this is quite suspicious that once you "downgraded" pointer type from `Derived*` to `Base*`, you want to access members which are specific to Derived.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we have to use dynamic_cast or static_cast, to call Derived::func2?

Yes.

> Is there another method?

Declare a virtual `Base::func2` function.

---

To clarify about covariance, it makes this possible:

```
Derived d{};
d->getThis()->func2();
```

Without covariance, `Derived* Derived::getThis` wouldn't be allowed and thus the above wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Covariant return types are merely a trick that allows the Liskov Substitution Principle to work while varying the return type in the derived class interface slightly. But the point of LSP remains: the base class interface is the interface. It's not a way to make a base class transparently provide stuff that's exclusively part of the derived class.

If you have a pointer/reference to the base class, calling `getThis` though that pointer/reference will *always* return a `Base*`. If you want to get at some derived class-only elements, you *must* always use some kind of cast.